# Objective C twitter client help!

Tags: objective-c, twitter, mgtwitterengine

I'm trying to update my app (iSocialNet) to use the latest version of MGTwitterEngine without success. I've successfully got iSocialNet to work using Ben Gottlieb's Twitter+OAuth, but there are issues that come with it.

What I would like to do is make my own 'TwitterEngine' but I'm not sure where to start. Can anyone please point me in the right direction? I must warn you that my knowledge of ObjC is minimal, but I'm getting there. Any help is appreciated.

The problem with Twitter+OAuth is that I can't get native retweets to show in the timeline, there's no retweet feature in the MGTE supplied, I can't get all users that a person follows and that's just what I've encountered so far. This is why i need to either update MGTE which comes with OAuth or i need to implement my own engine. I know that OAuth is tricky, but there's a library that MGTE uses that I would use. It's the actuall speaking to twitter that I don't understand.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to parse the timeline directly off twitter, I have same problem and I think it may solve the retweet problem as well as parse the follower list off twitter too ;)

Comment: i don't know how to make a call to twitter to get the data from twitter. is it a HTTPURL request?!?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to explain your problems with Ben Gottlieb's Twitter+OAuth here better than implementing a new OAuth engine, that's absolutely not trivial and with little Objective-C knowledgement it could be disappointing for you! We can help each other here and by reusing code.